# jQuery - find and replace substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Let's say I got strings like this

```
'Hello, I am ***Groot*** today.'
'This is ***not*** my final form.'
'Test test ***123***'
```

and I want to add some new stuff before the first and after the second asterix to make it look like

```
'Hello, I am FIRST***Groot***LAST today.'
'This is FIRST***not***LAST my final form.'
'Test test FIRST***123***LAST'
```

So far I managed to get this

```
var first =  jQuery(this).html().indexOf("***");
var last  =  jQuery(this).html().lastIndexOf("***");
console.log( jQuery(this).html().substring(first, last+3) );
```

but I fail on the replacement...so close, yet so far....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex pretty easily... this will work for all of your strings.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5dgvyz2/) (check js console)

```
var str = jQuery(this).text();
str = str.replace(/(\*{3}.*\*{3})/, "FIRST$1LAST");
console.log(str);
```

Also, you don't really need to create the jQuery objects just to get the text, could just do this:

```
var str = this.innerText;
str = str.replace(/\*{3}.*\*{3}/, "FIRST$&LAST");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct special replacement character in your replacement parameter should be `$&` rather than `$1` just for readability sake and best practices.

`$&` corresponds to the matched substring, whereas `$1` makes it seem like there are multiple matches in the RegExp object.

Reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace